# Accessing AngularJs directive scope.variable inside a controller

Tags: angularjs, controller, directive

```
return function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
    iElement.autocomplete({
        source:function(request, response) {
            var mastersList = new Array();
            var newRequest = request.term.substring(0, 3);
            if (request.term.length > 2 && scope.prerequest != newRequest) {
                scope.prerequest = newRequest;
                var url = "";
                if (scope.isCandidate == true) {
                    url = 'masters/getDataFromLookup/lkupid/' + scope.field.master_table_id + '/ac_param/' + newRequest + '/loginType/C';
                } else {
                    url = 'masters/getDataFromLookup/lkupid/' + scope.field.master_table_id + '/ac_param/' + newRequest;
                }
                HttpMethod.CallHttpMethod("GET", "", url).success(function(Resdata) {
                    var data = Resdata.data[0];
                    var masters = new Array();
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        var master = new Object();
                        var model = data;
                        master.name = model[i].name;

                        master.id = model[i].id;
                        mastersList.push(master);
                        masters.push(master);
                    }
                }
                response(mastersList);
                scope.masters = masters;
                )
            }
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $timeout(function() {
                scope.$parent.field.field_value = ui.item.name;
                scope.$parent.field.field_masterid = ui.item.id;
            },0);
        },
    });
}
```

This directive is to for auto complete feature.I have to access the values of scope.masters in my controller. Every time I try to access, it is undefined. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can set masters as isolated scope  "=" in your directive and access it in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make sure the directive sets it's scope to false so it does not use an isolated scope. Also you'll have to check the directive is located in the same scope as your controller. You can easily check this using a chrome extension like ng-inspect in which you can inspect angular scopes.

Outside of that it would be better to use an isolated scope and bind the variable to that scope, somewhat like:

```
scope: {
    masters: '=masters'
}
```

Then in your html

```
<input your-directive masters="masters" />
```

For more info: https://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/

Comment: <input type="{{field_datatype}}"
                                            autocompletemlookup prerequest  
                                          
                                           ng-ui-items="masters" masters="masters">

Comment: In controller I am using as mentioned below

 $scope.BindingMasterCode = function (field,event) {
             var tempField = $.grep($scope.masters, function (element) {
               
             });